# Why am I getting an access violation when locking a weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, access-violation, unhandled-exception, weak-ptr

I have a std::weak_ptr. Before attempting to use the underlying object, I lock it in order to get a shared_ptr:

```
auto foo_sharedptr = foo_weakptr.lock();
if (foo_sharedptr != nullptr)
{
    // do stuff with foo
}
```

Usually this works fine. However, sometimes I get an access violation during the call to lock:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF91F411BC3 (My.dll) in My.exe:  
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

My guess is that the underlying pointer has been deleted, but my understanding of weak_ptr is that in this case, lock should return a nullptr. Am I misusing the type? If not, how should I approach debugging this?

Comment: Not answering why the access violation happens, but you can use [`foo_weakptr.expired()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired)

Comment: If you look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/boost/weak_ptr.hpp, there is a note about access violation, is that related ?

Comment: @Appleshell, the spec states that expired() is effectively called by lock(): "Effectively returns expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this), executed atomically. "

Comment: @BlueTrin I think what they're saying here is that a ctor they're _not_ using can result in an access violation. I'm not using Boost though, so maybe my implementation has this problem. I hope not! Thanks.

Comment: I woulds guess that you've clobbered `foo_weakptr`, overwriting it with all-1 bits, so the access of the shared counter object fails.  You'll need to look at machine code before the actual faulting instruction to see where it is getting the 0xff..ff address

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Although upvoted, this does not seem to be correct answer, sorry:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp

```
template< class T >
bool operator==( const shared_ptr<T>& lhs, std::nullptr_t rhs );
    (7)     (since C++11)
template< class T >
bool operator!=( const shared_ptr<T>& lhs, std::nullptr_t rhs );
    (9)     (since C++11)
```

7) !lhs
**9) (bool)lhs**

....broken implementation?? Really don't know.

---

Test with gcc -std=c++11: (taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr and adapted)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::weak_ptr<int> gw;

void f()
{
    auto spt = gw.lock();
    if (spt != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *spt << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "gw is expired\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
        gw = sp;
        f();
    }

    f();
}
```

Output as expected:

```
42
gw is expired
```

**Must be elsewhere**

---

**Original:**

In short: check it as bool, do not compare to nullptr (that will try `lhs.get() == rhs.get()` which fails with rhs = shared_ptr on nullptr):

```
auto foo_sharedptr = foo_weakptr.lock();
if (foo_sharedptr)
{
    // do stuff with foo
}
```

[See the documentation:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

void observe(std::weak_ptr<int> weak) 
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> observe(weak.lock());
    if (observe) {
        std::cout << "\tobserve() able to lock weak_ptr<>, value=" << *observe << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "\tobserve() unable to lock weak_ptr<>\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::weak_ptr<int> weak;
    std::cout << "weak_ptr<> not yet initialized\n";
    observe(weak);

    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> shared(new int(42));
        weak = shared;
        std::cout << "weak_ptr<> initialized with shared_ptr.\n";
        observe(weak);
    }

    std::cout << "shared_ptr<> has been destructed due to scope exit.\n";
    observe(weak);
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of `== nullptr` and the conversion to `bool` is the same (unless there's a bug in the StdLib implementation). `operator bool` is defined in terms of `get() != 0`.

Comment: I tried checking for `if (foo_sharedptr)`, but am sometimes getting the same exception.